# tweepy V2: How to get user details when using search_recent_tweets?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

How do I get the user details like, user_id, First and Last name, etc for each tweet being retrieved from the Twitter API V2?

I'm using below working code, just not sure how to get the user details out:

```py
result = []; tweets = []; query="something"
client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token=bearer_token)
for tweet in tweepy.Paginator(
        client.search_recent_tweets
        , query = query
        , tweet_fields=['id', 'referenced_tweets','text','context_annotations','created_at','geo','author_id','lang','public_metrics','source']
        , user_fields =['id','name','username','url','public_metrics']
        , expansions=["referenced_tweets.id","author_id","geo.place_id",'referenced_tweets.id.author_id']
        ,max_results = 10).flatten(limit=10):

        tweets.append(tweet)
        result.append({'id': tweet.id,
                       'author_id': tweet.author_id,
                       'username': tweet.username,
                       'user_url': tweet.url,
                       'lang': tweet.lang,
                       'text': tweet.text,
                       'created_at': tweet.created_at,
                       'source':tweet.source,
                       'retweets': tweet.public_metrics['retweet_count'],
                       'replies': tweet.public_metrics['reply_count'],
                       'likes': tweet.public_metrics['like_count'],
                       'quote_count': tweet.public_metrics['quote_count'],
                       'referenced_tweets': tweet.referenced_tweets,
                       'context_annotations': tweet.context_annotations,
                       'geo': tweet.geo,
                       'tweet_url': f"https://twitter.com/{tweet.author_id}/status/{tweet.id}"
                  })
df = pd.DataFrame(result)
```

When I don't use user_fields this code works fin. But when i use user_fields and try to save them, this is throwing me an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-a3909bc89614> in <module>
     12         result.append({'id': tweet.id,
     13                        'author_id': tweet.author_id,
---> 14                        'username': tweet.username,
     15                        'user_url': tweet.url,
     16                        'lang': tweet.lang,

~/DATA_DIR/code-envs/python/translate_sa/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tweepy/mixins.py in __getattr__(self, name)
     33             return self.data[name]
     34         except KeyError:
---> 35             raise AttributeError from None
     36 
     37     def __getitem__(self, key):

AttributeError:
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use the .flatten() method on paginator when you need the author data of tweets (other than just author_id). what you are doing is achievable through the below code

```
result = []; tweets = []; query="something"
client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token=bearer_token)
for response in tweepy.Paginator(
    client.search_recent_tweets
    , query = query
    , tweet_fields=['id', 'referenced_tweets','text','context_annotations','created_at','geo','author_id','lang','public_metrics','source']
    , user_fields =['id','name','username','url','public_metrics']
    , expansions=["referenced_tweets.id","author_id","geo.place_id",'referenced_tweets.id.author_id']
    ,max_results = 10
    ,limit=1):
    
    usersdict = {x.id:x.username for x in response.includes['users']}
    for tweet in response.data:
        tweets.append(tweet)

        result.append({'id': tweet.id,
                       'author_id': tweet.author_id,
                       'username': usersdict[tweet.author_id],
                       'user_url': f"https://twitter.com/{usersdict[tweet.author_id]}/status/{tweet.id}",
                       'lang': tweet.lang,
                       'text': tweet.text,
                       'created_at': tweet.created_at,
                       'source':tweet.source,
                       'retweets': tweet.public_metrics['retweet_count'],
                       'replies': tweet.public_metrics['reply_count'],
                       'likes': tweet.public_metrics['like_count'],
                       'quote_count': tweet.public_metrics['quote_count'],
                       'referenced_tweets': tweet.referenced_tweets,
                       'context_annotations': tweet.context_annotations,
                       'geo': tweet.geo,
                       'tweet_url': f"https://twitter.com/{tweet.author_id}/status/{tweet.id}"
                  })
df = pd.DataFrame(result)
```